# 2D Array Void Dereferencing Definition Error in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, void-pointers

I want to create a dynamic dimensional matrix by taking the type variable from the user through the terminal. These types will be integer, float and double type matrices. But my function and matrix that I have defined in void type cannot do this job and I get an error. I think my problem is void dereferencing but I can't solve it. Thank you very much if you help.

I run it like this from terminal

```
./run arg1 arg2 i arg4 ... 
i = integer
f = float
d = double
```

The function I have written is as follows

```
void ** random_matrice_gen(int row, int column, int upper, int lower, char * option){

void **matrice;
if(strcmp(option,"i") == 0){
    matrice = malloc(row*sizeof(int *));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++){
        matrice[i] = malloc( column*sizeof(int) );  
    }
}
else if(strcmp(option,"f") == 0){
    matrice = malloc(row*sizeof(float *));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++){
        matrice[i] = malloc( column*sizeof(float) );    
        }
} else {

    matrice = malloc(row*sizeof(double *));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++){
        matrice[i] = malloc( column*sizeof(double) );   
    }
}

srand((unsigned)time(0));

for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<column; j++){
        
        if(strncmp(option,"i", 1) == 0){

            int rand_num_i = ((int) rand() / RAND_MAX) *  (int) ((upper- lower ) + lower);
            matrice[i][j] = rand_num_i;
        }
        else if(strncmp(option,"f" , 1) == 0){

            float rand_num_f = ((float) rand() / RAND_MAX) * (float)((upper- lower ) + lower);
            printf("%f debug f\n", rand_num_f);

            matrice[i][j] = rand_num_f;
        } else {

            double rand_num_d = ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX) *  (double) ((upper- lower) + lower);
            matrice[i][j] = rand_num_d;
        }
    }
}


return matrice;}
```

Errors as follows

```
'''50:15: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
   50 |     matrice[i][j] = rand_num_i;
      |               ^
matrixgen.c:50:19: error: invalid use of void expression
   50 |     matrice[i][j] = rand_num_i;
      |                   ^
matrisgen.c:57:15: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
   57 |     matrice[i][j] = rand_num_f;
      |               ^
matrixgen.c:57:19: error: invalid use of void expression
   57 |     matrice[i][j] = rand_num_f;
      |                   ^
matrixgen.c:61:15: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
   61 |     matrice[i][j] = rand_num_d;
      |               ^
matrixgen.c:61:19: error: invalid use of void expression
   61 |     matrice[i][j] = rand_num_d;
'''
```

Comment: `void **` => `double **`

Answer (score 0):

(void *) is a pointer to something unknown, as such, the size isn't known so you can't perform pointer arithmetic over it.

You need to cast it beforehand, ie

```
((int **)matrice)[i][j] = rand_num_i;
```

does compile.

Comment: the same error continues warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
   50 |     ((int **)matrice[i][j]) = rand_num_i;

Comment: You have an error on the closing parenthesis, it's `((int **)matrice)[i][j]`, not `((int **)matrice[i][j])`, see: https://godbolt.org/z/Ejx4j5

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to dereference `void *` pointers, and `matrice[i]` is such a pointer (and array indexing is equal to pointer dereference).

You need to cast this pointer to the correct type:

```
((int *) matrice[i])[j] = rand_num_i;
```

Comment: the same error continues warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
   50 |     (int *)matrice[i][j] = rand_num_i;

Comment: @testerenecmi Note the exact location of the *extra* parentheses. The casting is `((int *) matrice[i])`

Comment: I tried it in another way as you did, but it didn't work. ((int *) matrice[i])[j] = rand_num_i; or  ((int *) matrice[i])[j] ) = rand_num_i;